# Why is this not a valid XML DTD? (Parameter entity and #PCDATA)

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation, pcdata

Using the DTD validator [here](http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate/), I am informed that the following DTD is invalid.

```
<!ENTITY % text "(#PCDATA|L)*">
<!ELEMENT H         (%text;)+>
<!ELEMENT L         (#PCDATA)>
```

The error message is: "A '(' character or an element type is required within declaration of element type "H"." at line 2, column 22.

Can anyone please point out why it is invalid?  And how can I make it valid?  The error message is not exactly very friendly to me.  Thanks.

Comment: I could be mistaken that this is the error, but after resolving `%text;` you have two parentheses nested.

Comment: Hmmm, is having two parentheses nested an invalid thing in an XML DTD?  Not sure.  But if I remove the `#PCDATA` from the `%text;` entity declaration, so it becomes `<!ENTITY % text "(L)*">`, the DTD becomes valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot enforce that an element with mixed content must have at least one child node. Your DTD becomes

```
<!ELEMENT H         ((#PCDATA|L)*)+>
```

when the entity is expanded. The only allowed form for elements with mixed content is

```
(#PCDATA | A | B | C)*
```

where A, B and C are possible child elements. `#PCDATA` **must** be the first choice and the set must be allowed to repeat 0-infinity times, i.e. the asterisk is required.